# Weird error when trying to copy a list and insert an item to the beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of symbols that I use in a for loop. I'm trying to copy that list of symbols to a new list and insert a value in the first position of only the new list. I want the original list to be untouched.

```
self.symbols = ['CLE', 'RBE', 'HOE', 'CLES12Z', 'CLES6M', 'HOES1', 'RBES1', 'EP']

    if len(self.closes) == len(self.symbols)+1:
        key_list = self.symbols
        key_list.insert(0, 'Timestamp')
        print('length:{}'.format(len(self.symbols) + 1))
```

So basically, I check to see if a list called `self.closes` has the same number of items as my list of symbols. If it does, i want to create my new list  that has all the same values as the original self.symbols only with the word Timestamp in the first position.

I added that print statement to monitor what was going on and I noticed that the first time through, the output is 9 for the length of items in self.close (correct). However, the 2nd time through it becomes 10.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Shouldn't only key_list get the new item?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key_list = self.symbols` is not a copy. They both hold a reference to the same list.

Instead write:

```
key_list = self.symbols.copy()
```

Comment: For OP's benefit, the list-slicing syntax `self.symbols[:]` is a shorthand for this

Comment: Sure, whatever syntax suits you most. Imho, the newer copy() is more readable.